# Need simple definition for following

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am looking for single line definition to understand concepts or terms like below.
 I refered many sites even oracle.docs. But cant able to understand those concepts and map with real time scenerio..please help me to understand.

Thanks in advance.

```
    1)Normalization and its forms
    2)Table level locking and how to resolve it
    3)Dead locking and how to resolve it
    4)Cube and Rollup
    5)Table partition
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) Normalization and its forms**

> Normalization is a database design technique which organizes tables in
>   a manner that reduces redundancy and dependency of data. It divides
>   larger tables to smaller tables and links them using relationships.

There are several types of normalization form:

- 1NF (First Normal Form)
- 2NF (Second Normal Form)
- 3NF (Third Normal Form)
- Boyce-Codd Normal Form (BCNF)
- 4NF (Fourth Normal Form)
- 5NF (Fifth Normal Form)

Refer [this document](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html) for more information on normalization

**2) Table level locking and how to resolve it**

> According to Oracle documentation, A transaction automatically
>   acquires a table lock (TM lock) when a table is modified with the
>   following statements: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE, and SELECT ...
>   FOR UPDATE. These DML operations require table locks to reserve DML
>   access to the table on behalf of a transaction and to prevent DDL
>   operations that would conflict with the transaction.

Refer [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/ap_locks001.htm) for more information on Table level locking .

**3) Dead locking and how to resolve it**

> A deadlock occurs when two or more sessions are waiting for data
>   locked by each other, resulting in all the sessions being blocked.
>   Oracle automatically detects and resolves deadlocks by rolling back
>   the statement associated with the transaction that detects the
>   deadlock.

Refer [this document](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/deadlocks) for more information on Deadlock.

**4) Cube and Rollup**

ROLLUP :

> In addition to the regular aggregation results we expect from the
>   GROUP BY clause, the ROLLUP extension produces group subtotals from
>   right to left and a grand total.

CUBE:

> In addition to the subtotals generated by the ROLLUP extension, the
>   CUBE extension will generate subtotals for all combinations of the
>   dimensions specified.

Refer [this document](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets) for more information on ROLLUP and CUBE.

**5) Table partition**

> Partitioning allows a table, index, or index-organized table to be
>   subdivided into smaller pieces, where each piece of such a database
>   object is called a partition. Each partition has its own name, and may
>   optionally have its own storage characteristics.

There are several types of partitioning:
 - Range Partitioning Tables
 - Hash Partitioning Tables
 - Composite Partitioning Tables

Refer [this document](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/partitioned-tables-and-indexes) for more information on ROLLUP and CUBE.

Cheers!!